# Get the 5 most similar images

Tags: classification, similarity, sift, descriptor, vlfeat

I would like to compare which are the 5 most similar images to an input image.
To do this I thought to use the SIFT ([VLFeat library](http://www.vlfeat.org/index.html)) and compare the respective descriptors.
So I use the `vl_ubcmatch` (doc [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_ubcmatch.html)) method to calculate the similarity measurement between the images.

This is the code:

```
path_dir = './img/';
imgs = dir(path_dir);
imgs = imgs(3 : end); 
numImgs = size(imgs);
numImgs = numImgs(1);
path1 = './img/car01.jpg';
Ia = imread(path1);
Ia = single(rgb2gray(Ia));
[fa, da] = vl_sift(Ia);

results = struct;
m = 0;
j = 1; % indice dell'img (del for)

for img = imgs'

    path = strcat(path_dir, img.name);
    if(strcmp(path1, path) == 0)
        Ib = imread(path);
        Ib = single(rgb2gray(Ib));
        [fb, db] = vl_sift(Ib);

        [matches, scores] = vl_ubcmatch(da, db);

        s = sum(scores);
        [r, c] = size(scores);
        m = s ./ c;

        results(j).measure = m;
        results(j).img = path;
        j = j + 1;
    end
end
```

As you can see from the code, I thought I would use the mean as a measure of similarity but the results I get are not satisfactory (for example, it tells me that the input image of a cup is more similar to a tree than another cup).

According to you, is it better to have more equal descriptors but with low similar or less similar descriptors but with greater similarity?
I have 50 images of 5 different categories (cups, trees, people, tables and cars) and, given an image as input, the program will return the 5 most similar images to it and preferably belonging to the same category.

What measurement can I use instead of the mean to get a more precise classification?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code you measure the similarity between image (`Ia`) and all other images (`Ib`). Therefore you compare the SIFT descriptors of `Ia` with those of all `Ib`'s - which gives you a list of feature matches for each image pair (`matches`) and the Euclidean distance of each feature pair (`scores`).

Now using the mean of all `scores` of an image pair as a measure of similarity is not a very robust approach because an image pair with only one feature match could (by chance) lead to a better "similarity" than an image pair with many features - which I guess is an unrealistic solution for your task.

Concerning your question it is always better to have meaningful/robust descriptors, even if there are only a few (of course the more the better!), than having a lot of meaningless descriptors.

Proposal: why don't you just count the number of inliers (= number of feature matches for each image pair, `numel(matches)`)?

With this it should give more inliers between images of the same object than different objects, so taking those pairs which have the 5 most inliers should be the most similar ones.

If you just want to distinguish a cup from a tree it should work. If your classification task is getting more difficult and you need to distinguish different types of trees, SIFT is not the best algorithm to use. A learning approach will give better results... but depends on your task.